# Необходимо переделать не большую часть кода не используя циклы (for, while)

Tags: java

Имеется код, цель которого собрать всю информацию из csv файла (в котором находится информация о товарах), после чего код должен создать Entry класс для каждого отдельного продукта.

Необходимо переделать код без цикла for.

```
public class Repository {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "src/fp/sales/sales-data.csv";
    private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    public ArrayList<Entry> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public Repository() {
        try {
            List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(FILE_PATH));
            String cvsSplitBy = "\t";

            for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String[] products = list.get(i).split(cvsSplitBy);
                Entry product = new Entry();
                product.setDate(LocalDate.parse(products[0], formatter));
                product.setState(products[1]);
                product.setProductId(products[2]);
                product.setCategory(products[3]);
                product.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(products[5].replace(",", ".")));
                data.add(product);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "переделать код без цикла for" - зачем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Рекурсия

Если вы хотите сделать цикл без цикла, то у вас всегда только один вариант - рекурсия.

Если вы не знаете, что это такое, то объясню: это когда функция *(метод)* вызывает сама себя и сама себе передаёт параметры.

Вам надо создать вот примерно такой метод:

```
private SomeData cycle(int cyclesCount, SomeData some) {
    if (cyclesCount == 0) {
        return some;
    } else {
        // какая-то логика
    }
    cycle(--cyclesCount, some);
}
```

и вызвать этот метод вместо цикла. Вот и всё. Учитывайте только, что рекурсию априори лучше заменить на цикл. Ошибки в рекурсии могут зациклить программу. Ну и про StackOverFlow не забываем.

### Java 8

Если у вас есть требование, чтобы отсутствовал именно классический синтаксис цикла, то можно использовать метод forEach() *(на самом деле он не относится к Stream API, хотя многие путают)*. Вот так это будет:

```
list.forEach(productsEntry -> {
    String[] products = productsEntry.split(cvsSplitBy);
    Entry product = new Entry();
    product.setDate(LocalDate.parse(products[0], formatter));
    product.setState(products[1]);
    product.setProductId(products[2]);
    product.setCategory(products[3]);
    product.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(products[5].replace(",", ".")));
    data.add(product);
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я думал на счет рекурсии, однако надеялся на то, что есть более простой способ решения этой задачи, так как на этой неделе мы изучаем Stream API и все задания связаны с этим.

Comment: @RasmusRei а, я понял. Ну так StreamAPI, это тот же цикл, просто синтаксис другой. Сейчас подправлю ответ с учётом StreamAPI